# Graph optimization problem with multiple objectives/constraints

Tags: graph-theory, np-hardness, optimization, proofs, partition-problem

Let's assume that we have a directed acyclic graph $G = (V, E)$, non-negative vertex weight functions $w_a(v)$ and $w_b(v)$, and a non-negative edge weight function $t(u,v)$. We can divide vertices in two subsets $V_a$ and $V_b$, such that $V_a \cap V_b = \emptyset$ and $V_a \cup V_b = V$. A set of edges $E_{ab}$ between the two sets is defined as $(u,v) \in E_{ab}: (u \in V_a, v \in V_b) \lor (u \in V_b, v \in V_a)$

The cost function $C$ is described as follows:

$$C = \sum_{v \in V_a}{w_a(v)} + \sum_{v \in V_b}{w_b(v)} + \sum_{(u,v) \in E_{ab}}{t(u,v)}$$

We can also define the cost $C_P$ of a path $P : v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n$ using the same rules:

$$C_P = \sum_{v \in V_a \land v \in P}{w_a(v)} + \sum_{v \in V_b \land v \in P}{w_b(v)} + \sum_{(v_i, v_{i+1}) \in E_{ab} \land v_i \in P \land v_{i+1} \in P}{t(v_i,v_{i+1})}$$

Now, thanks to the user saisandeep, I know that the problem of finding the subsets $V_a$ and $V_b$ such that the $C$ function is minimized [can be reduced to minimum cut](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/37437/proof-that-the-graph-optimization-problem-is-np-hard), so it's in P.

I've also managed to come up with the solution to find the subsets with the shortest and longest possible path (or at least I hope that I did): we can transform the graph $G$ to graph $G'$ in such a way that for every vertex $v$ we create two vertices $v_a$ and $v_b$ with appropriate weights (from $w_a$ and $w_b$ functions respectively), and for every edge $(u,v)$ we create two edges with weight $0$: $(u_a,v_a)$, $(u_b,v_b)$; and two edges with weight $t(u,v)$: $(u_a,v_b)$, $(u_b,v_a)$. In other words, we're creating graph $G'$ that covers every possible path for every division of $V$.

The graph $G'$ is still a DAG, so both shortest and longest path can be found in polynomial time.

But what happens if I want to minimize the cost $C$ and at the same time restrict that the cost $C_P$ of the longest path must be below some maximal acceptable cost $c_{max}$?

Or the other way around: minimize the cost $C_P$ of the longest path, but keep the overall cost $C$ below $c_{max}$?

How should I approach this problem? Are there any generic ways to prove complexity of such multi-objective problems?

The best answer that I've found in literature is that *"multi-objective optimization problems are generally hard"* which is not very helpful.

My real-life application of this problem is to allocate software components on two heterogenous machines (hence two weight functions) connected via network (hence edge weights) and minimize both energy use (the $C$ function is basically the CPU time + transfer time) and the computation time (the longest path).

Thanks in advance for any help.